# WPF share data between pages

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new to WPF, and I wish to know, if the following is possible.

I have two WPF pages "Page_Parts" and "Page_Parts_Edit". Page_Parts has a link to call Page_Parts_Edit, and its contents of the entire page are displayed within Page_Parts.

Page_Parts contains a datagrid with all the parts in the system. I need to be able to click on a row within the datagrid and pass the selected row data to a textbox within the child page "Page_Parts_Edit". In essence allowing the user to select the part details from a given selection.

I'm able to do a similar approach when both objects are contained within the same WPF page, in the following manner:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextPartNumber" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPart, Path=SelectedItem.PartNumber}" Width="150" />
```

However, I'm not able to use the same approach when the datagrid is part of one page and the textbox is part of a different page.

Perhaps creating an array of strings, that the datagrid selected row updates which is linked to a DynamicResource, then bind the DynamicResource to the textboxes on the other page. Is that possible?

I'm open to any other suggestions.

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Alain

Comment: Pass the page in the ctor.  But you won't be able to use x:Name.  Bind SelectedItem to a public property.

Comment: Hi Blam, thanks for your feedback. Are you able to provide a quick sample, on how to implement the ctor option, to be able to share data across pages?